# How to repair KDE in Metamorphose Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, kde, metamorphosys

I'm using Metamorphose Linux 8, is Debian base and using KDE.

After I try instal teamview with official deb file and restart my computer, now my Linux are not start interface graphic.

It's enter terminal direct for me type username and password for login, and no have internet connection

What can I do to repair my graphic interface?

Comment: I think there are two possible causes: (1) when installing teamview, you didn't check what package were removed. (2) teamview messed your xorg conf.  In later case, check /var/log/Xorg.log.0 and give more details on what is the error.